# .NET Framework Class Library with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, msbuild

I have a .NET Framework (4.5.2) class library that I'd like to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection with as we're separately developing an ASP.NET Core app.

I installed it using nuget, it works fine when I build using Visual Studio but trying to build it using MSBuild on a TeamCity build agent gives me a lot of this:

```
MyClass.cs(32, 26): error CS0012: The type 'IServiceProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(33, 31): error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(33, 31): error CS1061: 'IServiceScope' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceScope' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
MyClass.cs(34, 10): error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(34, 10): error CS0012: The type 'IServiceProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(35, 10): error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(35, 10): error CS0012: The type 'IServiceProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(36, 51): error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(36, 51): error CS0012: The type 'IServiceProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
MyClass.cs(36, 30): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Some of the nuget packages (like Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection itself) don't have a separate net452 assembly and only netstandard1.0 or netstandard1.1. Could this be the issue? I installed the .NET Core SDK on the build server to no effect.

Comment: As expressed [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) and [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), class libraries should not use any DI library.

Comment: The library exposes an abstract Topshelf service class that is then implemented in a Console app, analogous to how ASP.NET is in practice a library that uses DI. I'm doing it this way so we don't need to copy paste boilerplate into every service we make.

Comment: There are many downsides to such approach, especially when you make use of the .NET Core DI abstraction which is a [Conforming Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/).

Comment: @JussiKosunen - "I'm doing it this way so we don't need to copy paste boilerplate into every service we make." - Do you have a `.config` file for every service you make? Think of the composition root as another (in code) `.config` file. You wouldn't share a `.config` file between applications, so why would you [share a composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/)?

Comment: The composition root is in the service, nothing is added to the container in the library implicitly. The library only provides a framework and utilities to make the experience as close as possible to ASP.NET Core. I'm attempting to prioritise making the service implementer's work easier rather than fussing about which assembly the ioc container is instantiated in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack, strange that all my other solutions built fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but after using NuGet Installer as a build step my all problems gets resolved.

Just you need to do one thing, before going to build your project - Just add one build step and select Runner type as NuGet Installer

You can check from this screenshots:

[image]

Comment: In this case I had already done this. The required assemblies (System.ComponentModel and System.Runtime) don't come as dependencies through NuGet, rather require either Visual Studio or the Developer Pack to be installed.